# How do I copy files without searching through them first?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I have about 4 million files I need to copy over the network to a windows 7 computer. I have been searching for a command or software that can do that without listing all the files since there are so many files It just takes up unnecessary time. So is there a program I can use which just start to copy immediately?

Comment: You can try `robocopy` command with `/MOVE /NDL /NFL` options. It will show error messages only.

Comment: @Sandeep That worked, thanks. I used `/NDL /NFL /E` since I want to keep the source files

Comment: @Sandeep: It would be good if you post your comment as an answer (that way this Q disappears from the list of unanswered questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) command has all features you need.

As mentioned in comments, to move files, you can use `robocopy` command with `/MOVE /NDL /NFL` options. To keep source files (copy only), you can use `/NDL /NFL /E` options.

No official GUI is available for this command. However, few experimental GUI are available. It seems that not all parameters/options are supported by these GUIs. These GUI can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) and [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/whats-new-in-windows-7-robocopy).